# Why can't I upload Process Templates to TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-process-template

I am trying to upload a custom process template to Microsoft Team Foundation Server in the cloud on visualstudio.com, but the Process Template Manager Window looks like this:

[image]

I've checked my permissions:

[image]

and made sure I'm member of the relevant groups (Project Collection Administrators, etc.). I've started Visual Studio as Administrator to make sure I'm local administrator. I can set the existing templates as default and downloading the templates works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What would you like to customize?  Is there something in particular you are hoping to customize within the process template?

Comment: I would like to create custom work items with properties and states... Do you know a workaround?

Comment: Thanks Marc - it sounds like you are wanting to create new work item types in addition to the ones available in the default process templates.  What kinds of new work items are you trying to create?  What's your scenario that is missing from the default process templates.

Comment: We currently don't have a workaround at the moment with Visual Studio Online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing a process template or adding a custom process template is not yet available for Visual Studio Online. There is a [fairly popular user voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3654231-customize-team-foundation-service-process-template) to add this feature.